# c# getting both string and integer values while iterating over an enum

Tags: c#

I have the following Enum :

```
public enum Flow
{
    All = 0,
    One = 1
}
```

i'am iterating :

```
foreach(var flow in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Flow)))
{
    Flows.Add(new FlowType()
    {
        FlowId = (int)flow,
        FlowName = (string)flow
    });
}
```

I'm always getting the string value and exception on the int value :

Cannot convert type System.String to integer

Comment: use `ToString()`

Comment: @sebastianhofmann the problem appears to be converting string to int.  He should use `Convert.ToInt32()` or `int.TryParse()`, or `Cast` the result of GetValues to his enum type

Comment: What is the type of FlowId and FlowName? My guess is you copied FlowId to FlowName and forgot to change datatype from int to string

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUPoAj

Comment: I call shenanigans, this doesn't make any sense (in several ways)

Comment: Sounds like your `FlowName` is an `int`.

Comment: Aside from the issues already raised by various people, what is the use case for declaring an enum, and then using reflection (slow!) to iterate over the possible values?

Comment: @dumetrulo Please explain what makes you think this code is slow. This is a very common approach to let users select values from Enums as well

Comment: @dumetrulo: there is no reflection used

Comment: What is the definition of your FlowType?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
public enum Flow
{
    All = 0,
    One = 1
}
public static void EnumerateEnum()
{
    foreach (var flow in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Flow)))
    {
        int FlowId = (int)flow;
        string FlowName = flow.ToString();
    }
}
```